# Concatenar time Django

Tags: python, django

Tengo un proyecto en django donde tengo los campos hora, minutos, segundos por separados necesito **concatenarlos** para que me queden en el formato **"%H:%M:%S"**

```
direferencia=6243.0 #Este valor esta en segundos

hora=math.floor(diferencia/3600) #devuelve 1.0

minuto=math.floor((diferencia - (hora * 3600)) / 60) #devuelve 44.0

segundo=math.floor(diferencia - (hora * 3600 + minuto * 60))#devuelve 3.0
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Es más sencillo de lo que estás haciendo, usa el módulo [time](https://docs.python.org/2/library/time.html)

```
>>> import time
>>> time.strftime('%H:%M:%S', time.gmtime(6243.0))
    '01:44:03'
>>>
```

Esto es a lo que me refería en el comentario

```
>>> import datetime
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=86400))
'1 day, 0:00:00'
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=86401))
'1 day, 0:00:01'
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=86400))
'1 day, 0:00:00'
>>> str(datetime.timedelta(seconds=86399))
'23:59:59'
```

Comment: Recuerda, esto solo funciona cuando los segundos son menores  a 86399, por que de lo contrario si son mayores a 86400 obtendrás 0:00:00.